# Issue with $.getJSON in Xcode 4 + phone gap

Tags: jquery, xcode, xcode4, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using PhoneGap 1.2.0 and Xcode 4. I have a
JSON data file "appData.json", which i have stored in www folder with
"index.html". I want to access the data from "appData.json" using the following code:

```
    $.getJSON("appData.json",function(results){alert(results);});
```

But it is not working. I think the problem is with URL of the file. The
code is not able to access the `appData.json` file.
This code is working fine in Adobe Dreamweaver 5.5.
Looking forward to your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the format of your JSON data?

```
$.getJSON("appData.json",function(results){alert(results);});
```

The above works fine for me on Xcode 4.2 and PhoneGap 1.2.0.

My 'appData.json' file contained:

`[{"foo":"bar"},{"yadda":"yadda"}]`

[image: blank new PhoneGap app with code above added]

Comment: {
    "LightA": {
        "d1": "2167",
        "d2": "1959",
        "d3": "1759",
        "d4": "1472",
        "d5": "1220",
        "d6": "1015",
        "d7": "890",
        "d8": "820",
        "d9": "769",
        "d10": "708"
    }} where is ur appData.json is located?? mine is in www folder..

Comment: So is mine. Using your data works fine too, so I am not sure what is going wrong for you. Are you sure jQuery is loading OK? Are you calling the $.getJSON() from within document ready? If you have any JavaScript files being loaded from an external host have you made sure to add that host to your ExternalHosts key in PhoneGap.plist?

Comment: im also using adobe dreamweaver 5.5 (phone gap + jquery mobile integrated)..it's working fine there..

Comment: It could be the ExternalHosts thing then, because I believe the PhoneGap in Dreamweaver is pre 1.0 whitelists. - http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/40796976/Install%20the%20latest%20(trunk)%20source%20of%20iOS%20PhoneGap

Comment: no luck...can u paste the whole code..? so that i can check which .js files u have included..

Comment: i have added appData.json in externalhosts in phonegap.plist..but it's not working..:(

Comment: Code is at: http://pastebin.com/DRRa725F  - ExternalHosts is not needed if your jQuery and other JavaScript files are all local (i.e.: in the www folder) and so is your JSON file. ExternalHosts is for allowing access to external hosts such as ajax.googleapis.com, etc. Worst case simply add the * wildcard as an item under ExternalHosts and you should be covered.

Comment: i have tried ur code also...but no solution...i don't knw whats going wrong..i really need this thing to be solved...

Comment: You don't get the alert with my index.html in a fresh PhoneGap project with your JSON data in that file? I don't know what to say.

Comment: it's working now..i have replaced the jquery-1.5.min.js file with jquery-1.7.min.js in my project and it's working fineee now..thank you very much for your help!!!